# Solving for a vector $x$ given $Ax=b$

Tags: matrices

This is a dumb question I know.

If I have matrix equation $Ax = b$ where $A$ is a square matrix and $x,b$ are vectors, and I know $A$ and $b$, I am solving for $x$.

But multiplication is not commutative in matrix math. Would it be correct to state that I can solve for $A^{-1}Ax = A^{-1}b \implies x = A^{-1}b$?

Comment: Do you know that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: As long A is invertible, yes $x=A^{-1}b$

Comment: @Sloan I don't know. I think so? Not sure how to tell. I am not even sure how to compute the inverse yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the matrix is invertible, this is correct and the equation has the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$.

Here is the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) of properties that make a matrix invertible.

Comment: So if I were to try to invert the matrix, how would I know if I failed? Do I have to compute the determinant first to ensure it isn't 0, or will there be some problem that occurs naturally?

Comment: If the matrix $A$ is not invertible, you cannot find a matrix $B$ such that $BA=I$. For example, the Gauss Algortihm will not work.

Since, there is a long list of properties it is usually easier to check one of them first, instead of trying and failing.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is invertible, the answer is yes. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to write that. Also in that case you may not have any solution.

Comment: well you might also have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible then your solution works. Use this little result to determine if $A$ is invertible:

$A^{-1}$ exists $\Leftrightarrow$ det($A$) $\neq 0$. Where det($A$) is the determinant of $A$.

A little reading on determinants: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you are solving for $x$, the easiest way which is also safe to "work", is Gaussian Elimination. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)
It also tells you, if there are no or infinitely many solutions.

Inverting a matrix is only sometimes possible and almost never faster (if you are only solving one system involving said matrix) for $3\times 3$ or higher. If $A$ is invertible, then there is of course always a unique solution $x$.